# Issue with UILongPressGestureRecognizer while using it in table view cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I am implementing a long press in the uitableview through storyboard in swift3. I have only one prototype cell set in the storyboard. But the problem is the long press is being detected only in the first cell. Rest of the cells are not listening to the long press gesture.

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Label"

        return cell
}

    @IBAction func longPress(_ guesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

        if guesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
            print("Long Press")
        }
    }
```

The warning shown in the console is:

**at a time, this was never allowed, and is now enforced. Beginning with iOS 9.0 it will be put in the first view it is loaded into.**

Comment: What view are you attaching the gesture to?

Comment: uitableview cell

Comment: Just add longpressgesture to whole tabelview

Comment: @JitendraModi Thanks man i got it....

Comment: As per below answer, logpress gesture allocate every time your method calls. Instead of it you can add gesture directly to tabelview So it will initiate only once. and used for all cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add gesture for all cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Label"

        let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.longPress(_:)))
        cell?.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
        return cell
}



func longPress(_ guesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

        if guesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
            print("Long Press")
        }
    }
```

Comment: why down voting ?

Comment: You should not attach a gesture for every cell.  It is better to create one gestureRecongnizer and put it on the tableview.  see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/IncorporatingGestureSupport/IncorporatingGestureSupport.html  " The UICollectionView class is a descendant of UIScrollView, so attaching your gesture recognizers to the collection view is less likely to interfere with the other gestures that must be tracked."

Answer (score 4):

Attach the gesture to the tableview, and when the gesture is triggered figure out which indexPath was selected.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
       let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longPress(_:)))
    tableView?.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
}

func longPress(_ guesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if guesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
        let point = guesture.location(in: tableView)
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point);
        print("Long Press \(String(describing: indexPath))")
    }
}
```

Because a tableview is a kind of scrollview it is best to attach the gestures to the tableview itself and not any of its subview.  This way it is less likely to interfere with the other gestures that must be tracked.